# How to insert case statement in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

My query is below, What I need is when I pass -1 in parameter no condition should call else when other value are passes It should call the condition

I have tried below query but its not working

```
SELECT RequestID
     , AgencyName
     , Contact
     , DeliveryAddress
     , ContactPhone
     , ContactEmailAddress
     , RequestDate
     , CASE WHEN RequestStatus=0 THEN 'Pending' 
            ELSE CASE WHEN RequestStatus=1 THEN 'Approved' 
                      ELSE 'Denied' 
                 END 
       END AS 'RequestStatus'
    FROM tblRequest 
    WHERE CASE WHEN @RequestStatus=-1 THEN '0'='0' 
               ELSE RequestStatus= @RequestStatus 
          END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - CASE expression inside WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414431/sql-case-expression-inside-where)

Comment: 0=0 means true so all values should be returned when -1?  or do you want no values? or something else?  I'm not following. and what should be the value of 'RequestStatus' when -1 is input; Null?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean:

The issue is you can't control an entire expression in the where clause just one side of it at a time using case; Otherwise you have dynamic SQL and would have to manage an other way.

```
SELECT RequestID
     , AgencyName
     , Contact
     , DeliveryAddress
     , ContactPhone
     , ContactEmailAddress
     , RequestDate
     , CASE WHEN RequestStatus=0 THEN 'Pending' 
            ELSE CASE WHEN RequestStatus=1 THEN 'Approved' 
                      ELSE 'Denied' 
                 END 
       END AS 'RequestStatus'
    FROM tblRequest 
    WHERE RequestStatus = CASE WHEN @RequestStatus=-1 THEN RequestStatus
                               ELSE @RequestStatus 
                          END
```

Answer (score 1):

`case` can be used to choose between values, not syntactic elements. You can emulate the behavior you want with a straight-forward `or` operator:

```
WHERE @RequestStatus = -1 OR RequestStatus = @RequestStatus
```

Or just use the `in` operator as a shortcut:

```
WHERE @RequestStatus IN (-1, RequestStatus)
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP wanted. If `RequestStatus` is -1, the `WHERE` should just read `0=0`. However, `RequestStatus  = -1` isn't equal to `0=0`.

Comment: This does do what the OP wanted. The predicate returns true if `@RequestStatus` is `-1` (give me all rows) or if `RequestStatus` is equal to `@RequestStatus` (give me a subset).